# unable to read Mifare ultralight using android phone

Tags: android, nfc

I am Writing following data on **TAG 2 Type mifare ultralight (48 bytes) with static memory** using USB NFC Reader ACR122U Successfully

Below is the data written on a TAG  from 4th block and block size is 4 bytes

**03 20 d1 01 1c 54 02 65 6e 53 6f 6d 65 20 72 61 6e 64 6f 6d 20 65 6e 67 6c 69 73 68 20 74 65 78 74 2e FE 00**

when  I try to Read Data Using  NFC enabled Android Phone(Lava XOLO Model X900 with Platform 2.3.7) it does not detect the TAG.

Please Help!!!

thanks in advance

Comment: First of all make sure that NFC is activated on your phone. What application did you use to read the tag ? Have you tried with NXP Taginfo app ?

Comment: What is the contents of block 2 and 3?

Comment: @ Damien Dub My Device is NFC enabled and I had Set NFC check enabled from wireless & Networks

Comment: If you want to be detected as NDEF Tag you should set correctly the OTP bytes in page 3.

Comment: finally i am able to do this working.There was problem in handset Lava XOLO Model X900 . The tag was successly working on Sony Xperia and also working Blackberry handset 9360

Answer (score -1):

There could be some compatibility issue on your phone NFC with the TAG you are using, 

check a detailed information here. http://www.andytags.com/nfc-tags-compatibility-issues.html#.UjF9BX-2_2U

Here is a chunk of info provided there:
NXP has been one of the leading manufacturers of NFC hardware and pretty much all Android phones up to a certain point used NXP hardware.  The NFC Forum was established to create protocols for NFC so that any hardware and any microchip (NFC Tag) that adheres to this protocol will be compatible.  NXP created the Mifare Classic 1K Chip specifically to be compatible with it's hardware and not necessarily to adhere to the protocols.  While these chips are compatible with NXP hardware which covers the majority of the NFC equipped phones and tablets on the market, the chips are not necessarily compatible with any phone that uses other manufacturer's hardware.  On the Nexus 4 and 10, the Galaxy S4, and the newer 2013 Nexus 7 a different manufacturer's NFC hardware (Broadcom) was used.  Because of this only chips which adhere to the NFC Forum's Protocols are completely compatible meaning the Mifare Classic chips are not.  The only info the Broadcom NFC hardware can read off a Mifare Classic Chip is the UID# (kind of like a UPC code for NFC Tags).  It can not write to them at all and can not read anything else that has been written to them.

Comment: That does not apply to the Mifare Ultralight, only to the Mifare Classic chips.

Comment: but in my case, i am unable to read Ultralight using intent filter of ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, rather i have to use ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED same as mentioned in this article.